# Set home up button

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to set the Home Up Button in my PreferenceScreen so i tried with this code

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

My App require minSdkVersion10 (GB) so i check the android version with Build.VERSION.SDK_INT. The problem is that eclipse give me an error on getActionBarMethod() because "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 10): android.preference.PreferenceActivity#getActionBar" How can i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to the your method above where you use this code,

In this case i used onCreate method.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") or @TargetApi(HONEYCOMB)

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){

 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For you to use actionbar on gingerbread your best solution would be to use ActionBarSherlock library by Jake Wharton